# Magento 2 - Override Model Failed

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, preference

I try to override the Customer model. I created `code/Tc/Name/etc/di.xml`,  `code/Tc/Name/Model/Customer/Customer.php` .

In `di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Customer" type="Tc\Name\Model\Customer\Customer" />
</config>
```

In `Customer.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tc\Name\Model\Customer;

class Customer extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
{

   public function getName()
    {              
        $name = '';

        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= ' ' . $this->getLastname();

        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .= $this->getFirstname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Nothing changed after `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:deploy`. I tried to add a code to dump log in `getName()` but also nothing logged.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `var/generation` folder, you need to do that after make change in `di.xml` file

Comment: Thanks. Just tried to do `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*`. Then `setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, setup:static-content:deploy`. But not working. No error and no different

Comment: I also added `etc/module.xml` and `registration.php`. The module added success and enable it in admin panel. However, it is still not working.

Comment: Where are you check `getName()` after override model?

Comment: I use `fopen` and `fwrite` in `getName()` to dump a log file. I also tried to use `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')` to dump the debug log file. But seems it was not trigged

Comment: I had something similar before and all I had forgotten was to enable to module using `module:enable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem before, I added `__construct` and `variables`, its works fine,

Try this code:

```
<?php

namespace Tc\Name\Model\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer as ResourceCustomer;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;


class Customer extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
{

 /**
     * Configuration paths for email templates and identities
     */
    const XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/create_account/email_template';

    const XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY = 'customer/create_account/email_identity';

    const XML_PATH_REMIND_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/password/remind_email_template';

    const XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/password/forgot_email_template';

    const XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY = 'customer/password/forgot_email_identity';

    const XML_PATH_RESET_PASSWORD_TEMPLATE = 'customer/password/reset_password_template';

    const XML_PATH_IS_CONFIRM = 'customer/create_account/confirm';

    const XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/create_account/email_confirmation_template';

    const XML_PATH_CONFIRMED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/create_account/email_confirmed_template';

    const XML_PATH_GENERATE_HUMAN_FRIENDLY_ID = 'customer/create_account/generate_human_friendly_id';

    const SUBSCRIBED_YES = 'yes';

    const SUBSCRIBED_NO = 'no';

    const ENTITY = 'customer';

    const CUSTOMER_GRID_INDEXER_ID = 'customer_grid';

    /**
     * Configuration path to expiration period of reset password link
     */
    const XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_RESET_PASSWORD_LINK_EXPIRATION_PERIOD = 'customer/password/reset_link_expiration_period';

    /**
     * Model event prefix
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'customer';

    /**
     * Name of the event object
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'customer';

    /**
     * List of errors
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_errors = [];

    /**
     * Assoc array of customer attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_attributes;

    /**
     * Customer addresses collection
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection
     */
    protected $_addressesCollection;

    /**
     * Is model deletable
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_isDeleteable = true;

    /**
     * Is model readonly
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_isReadonly = false;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_config;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var Share
     */
    protected $_configShare;

    /**
     * @var AddressFactory
     */
    protected $_addressFactory;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_addressesFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_groupRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface
     */
    protected $_encryptor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Math\Random
     */
    protected $mathRandom;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    protected $dateTime;

    /**
     * @var CustomerInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $customerDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var DataObjectProcessor
     */
    protected $dataObjectProcessor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
     */
    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface
     */
    protected $metadataService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry
     */
    protected $indexerRegistry;


  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $config,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer $resource,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share $configShare,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\CollectionFactory $addressesFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
    CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
    DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $metadataService,
    \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
    ) {
    $this->metadataService = $metadataService;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_config = $config;
    $this->_configShare = $configShare;
    $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    $this->_addressesFactory = $addressesFactory;
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    $this->_groupRepository = $groupRepository;
    $this->_encryptor = $encryptor;
    $this->customerDataFactory = $customerDataFactory;
    $this->dataObjectProcessor = $dataObjectProcessor;
    $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
    $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $storeManager,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data
    );
    }

   public function getName()
    {              
    $name = '';

    if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
        $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
    }
    $name .= ' ' . $this->getLastname();

    if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
        $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
    }
    $name .= $this->getFirstname();
    if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
        $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
    }
    return $name;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have error.

Comment: Good to see an error. At least I know that this model is called after adding the `__construct` and `variables`

Comment: I have this error `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Customer::__construct() must implement interface Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManagerInterface, instance of Magento\\Customer\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Customer\\Interceptor given, called in /var/www/html/app/code/Tc/Name/Model/Customer/Customer.php on line 250 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer.php:234 `

Comment: @now try this let me know you have any error

Comment: Please check the error on the above comment. I have double checked the parameters and implementations which are same as `module-customer/Model/Customer.php`

Comment: you need to change some pareameters form core, Now check it, I have changed argument 3($resource argument  need StoreManagerInterface)

Comment: After I added the $storeManager, the error shows that $config is missing. So I added all the parameters to it `$context,$registry,$storeManager,$config,$scopeConfig,$resource,            $configShare,$addressFactory,$addressesFactory,$transportBuilder,            $groupRepository,            $encryptor,            $dateTime,            $customerDataFactory,            $dataObjectProcessor,
            $dataObjectHelper,            $metadataService,            indexerRegistry,            $resourceCollection,            $data`.  After that no error, no different and no log.

Comment: add one by one and test it will fix ..

Comment: Tried. It keeps returning this kind of error. `Argument 18 passed to Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Customer::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\Indexer\\IndexerRegistry, null given,` , `Argument 17 passed to Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Customer::__construct() must implement interface Magento\\Customer\\Api\\CustomerMetadataInterface` .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite only getName() function you can create plugin instead of overwriting the entire customer Model. Any of the public function in model we can create plugin.

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure the usage of plugin. I think it is adding methods before or after the core methods. For my case, should I add a plugin to rewrite the name after getName()?

Comment: @user631607 , could you explain your case.

Comment: I want to show the name in `Lastname` `Firstname` format instead of `firstname` `lastname` for Japanese store.

Comment: @user631607 you can use after method ( afterGetName ) plugin for your case.  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html